# Deserialize boolean to string

Tags: java, serialization

There is a dto class. I have a boolean field there. I want to get this field in another class and want to set this field as set string (yes/no) insteado of boolean (true / false)

in dto  i have this.

```
 //dto class
@ExportField(columnName = "K", headerName = "export.available")
private Boolean isAvailable;
```

i converted to this

```
    @JsonDeserialize(using=StringBooleanDeserializer.class)
@ExportField(columnName = "K", headerName = "export.available")
private Boolean isAvailable;
```

this is my deserialize class

```
public class StringBooleanDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {
    protected static final String NO = "no";
    protected static final String YES = "yes";

    @Override
    public Boolean deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String text = jsonParser.getText();
        if(YES.equals(text)) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

in another class i call dto

```
     Dto dto = Dto()
            ;
            .setIsAvailable(variant.isAvailable());




System.out.println(dto.getIsAvailable);
```

i want to see as string, not boolean. Actually i export this, not system out but. same logic.

or are there any otherways?

Comment: you should deserialize and then assign the value in other string variable.

Comment: if i am not wrong , you want `dto.getIsAvailable()` to o/p as `YES` or `NO` , after it goes through your deserializer and isAvailable is a Boolean in your DTO, correct ?

Comment: than its not possible. as i suggested earlier you have to use another `string` variable.

Comment: So, another dto class?

Comment: Why would you need a whole new class? Wouldn't it be enough to add a method to expose the attribute as a `String`?